# Stacking of Context Menus in Electron

Tags: node.js, menu, ipc, electron, atom-editor

I am building an Electron based application that contains a grid containing unique rows. I would like a context-menu that is specific to each row. Here is an example:

[image: Image of GUI with context menu]

Although this screen shot is cropped, you can see there are multiple rows and each row contains separate data. Since I'd like to right-click on a row and get a unique context menu, I have implemented [electron-context-menu](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu), which does work on the first right click, but then subsequent right-clicks causes a stacking effect of context menus.

Specifically, here is what happens:

1. I right click on Row-1 and the proper context menu shows up
2. I right click on Row-2 and a repeat of the context menu for Row-1 shows up then Row-2's context menu shows up. (Notice in the screen shot the context menu showing does not correspond to the row my mouse is over)
3. This repeats itself.

In React.JS, here is my listener, which collects the `contextmenu` object as needed by the `electron-context-menu` module:

```
  handleContextMenu() {
    this.props.contextMenu({
      window: electron.remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(),
      prepend: (params, browserWindow) => [{
        label: `Library Compare ${this.state.msn}`,
        click: () => this.runLibCompare()
      }],
      append: (params, browserWindow) => [{
        label: '---',
      }]
    })
  };
```

Where `this.props.contextMenu(...)` perculates up the React.JS components to be fed into:

```
const contextMenu = eRequire('electron-context-menu');
```

I have done some massive debugging and I don't think the issue is the module. The module I am using essentially organizes the information about the context menu and then uses `electron.remote` functions and a `menu.popup` function which comes from electron internals. Here is a link to the [specific line in github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu/blob/master/index.js#L118).

```
const menu = (electron.Menu || electron.remote.Menu).buildFromTemplate(menuTpl);
menu.popup(electron.remote ? electron.remote.getCurrentWindow() : win);
```

This call to `menu.popup` leads to this [line in electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/bad130f623d1ed0de1a61bc3e82ae553fbf46364/lib/renderer/api/remote.js#L113).

```
  const remoteMemberFunction = function (...args) {
    if (this && this.constructor === remoteMemberFunction) {
      // Constructor call.
      let ret = ipcRenderer.sendSync('ELECTRON_BROWSER_MEMBER_CONSTRUCTOR', metaId, member.name, wrapArgs(args))
      return metaToValue(ret)
    } else {
      // Call member function.
      let ret = ipcRenderer.sendSync('ELECTRON_BROWSER_MEMBER_CALL', metaId, member.name, wrapArgs(args))
      return metaToValue(ret)
    }
```

}

So I see a call to `ipcRender.sendSync` -- however when I add debugging statements in `ipcMain`'s [receiver of those calls](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/bad130f623d1ed0de1a61bc3e82ae553fbf46364/lib/browser/rpc-server.js#L357), I don't see any output!

```
ipcMain.on('ELECTRON_BROWSER_MEMBER_CALL', function (event, id, method, args) {
  try {
    args = unwrapArgs(event.sender, args)
    let obj = objectsRegistry.get(id)

    if (obj == null) {
      throwRPCError(`Cannot call function '${method}' on missing remote object ${id}`)
    }

    callFunction(event, obj[method], obj, args)
  } catch (error) {
    event.returnValue = exceptionToMeta(error)
  }
})
```

When I added debug statements to the above function, I didn't see any output. And that is where my search his a wall.

I am using electron 1.4.15. I know this issue should be resolvable, after-all the Atom IDE (which is electron based) does not have this issue even though it has multiple context menus.

I think there is some memory I need to clear somewhere, I just can't figure out how to clear the stack of previous context menus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this by first getting the target of the click using e.target. Then, depending on that, I call the corresponding contextmenu. If target hit is not in the list of targets for my app, I use a default contextmenu.

```
window.addEventListener(
    "contextmenu",
    e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.target.id === 'fullscr'){

        console.log(e && e.target);

       // e.preventDefault();
        mymenu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow());
        }else{
            editmenu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow());
        }
        console.log(e.which);
    },
    false
);
```