# How to de-register context menu listerners in electron

Tags: node.js, event-handling, mouseevent, contextmenu, electron

I previously wrote this question [Stacking of Context Menus in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148183/stacking-of-context-menus-in-electron) and created this issue in the [context menu module for electron](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu/issues/30).

Even though my question above is quite detailed, it got no replies. Then, [@sindresorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus) recommended I ask this question on StackOverflow:

How do I de-register context menu's in electron? I have a program in which, depending on where you click, a different context menu will show up:

```
  handleContextMenu() {
    this.props.contextMenu({
      prepend: (params, browserWindow) => [{
        label: `Summary ${this.state.msn}`,
        click: () => this.createSummary()
      },{
        label: `Library Compare ${this.state.msn}`,
        click: () => this.runLibCompare()
      },{
        label: `Visualize ${this.state.msn}`,
        click: () => dialog.showMessageBox({
            type: 'question',
            buttons: this.vizButtons,
            defaultId: 0,
            title: `Choose your visualization`,
            message: `Choose your visualization for ${this.state.msn}.`,
          }, res => this.visualize(res))
      }]
    });
  };
```

However, when I right-click on another area, the first context menu pops up, then the second, all the way till the current context menu shows up.

I basically want to de-register a context menu after it has been dismissed. How do I do that?

Update:
Got rid of the context menu and simply fed this to `handleContextMenu` function:

```
  handleContextMenu = menuItems => {
    const menu = new electron.remote.Menu();
    menu.append(new electron.remote.MenuItem(menuItems));
    menu.popup(electron.remote.getCurrentWindow());
  }
```

And it works! That's that, got rid of the electron-context-menu as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with standard [Electron Menu API](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/) without additional modules, perhaps using `electron-context-menu` is just complicating things since that seems to be designed to simplify things for the specific use-case of a standard context menu. With the standard Menu API, you can create and pop-up a menu on each click, so there is no need to "de-register" a menu.

Here's a simplified example, creating a different new context menu with each click:

```
let menuCount = 1;
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let menu = new electron.remote.Menu();
  menu.append(new electron.remote.MenuItem({label : "Context Menu "+menuCount++}))
  menu.popup(electron.remote.getCurrentWindow());
});
```

On the first right-click you will see a menu with an item "Context Menu 1", on the second right-click, "Context Menu 2", and so on.

Comment: No.. I replaced my code with your exact suggestion and I still get the stacking effect.. Now it says n...n-1...3...2...1

Comment: I wonder if I need to come up with a way to remove the menu from the eventLisenter?

Comment: Oh wait... I think I got it. I removed the window.addEventListener and it doesn't seem to be repeating. Let me flesh this out some more

Comment: Giving you credit for the answer, even though I still had to tweak you. You set me on the right path, sir!

Comment: Thanks. I gave a simplified example as answer as I don't really know React so was not confident I could write code you could just drop in to yours.